# "TypeError: i18nService.getSafeText is not a function" when rendering data for grid using angular-ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, translation, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I have imported the `ui-grid` module in my app's module import file:
`import 'angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.core';`

Added in the same file this imported module:

```
const app = angular
  .module('app', [
    uiRouter,
    uiBootstrap,
    'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker',
    'ui.grid',
    [...]
    ])
```

And in controller for view which will use the grid, I've set gridOptions:

```
this.gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [
    {name: "Account", field: "accountNumber", enableCellEdit: false},
    {name: "dateFrom", field: "dateFrom", enableCellEdit: false},
    {name: "dateTo", field: "dateTo", enableCellEdit: false},
    {name: "operationsType", field: "operationType", enableCellEdit: false},
    {name: "someId", field: "someId", enableCellEdit: false}
  ]
};
[...]
const jsonObj = this.XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheetObj, {header: ["accountNumber", "dateFrom", "dateTo", "operationType", "someId"]});
this.gridOptions.data = jsonObj;
```

And set grid element in view:

```
<div ng-if="vm.gridOptions.data" id="grid1" ui-grid="vm.gridOptions"
     class="grid col-xs-12">
</div>
```

But when rendering the grid, I get error in console:

```
TypeError: i18nService.getSafeText is not a function
    at Object.link (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js?97065532baea04c9b656:4815:1), <anonymous>:2158:28)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js?97065532baea04c9b656:2394:1), <anonymous>:1247:18)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js?97065532baea04c9b656:2394:1), <anonymous>:9928:44)
    at invokeLinkFn (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js?97065532baea04c9b656:2394:1), <anonymous>:9934:9)
    at nodeLinkFn (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js?97065532baea04c9b656:2394:1), <anonymous>:9335:11)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js?97065532baea04c9b656:2394:1), <anonymous>:9673:13)
    at processQueue (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js?97065532baea04c9b656:2394:1), <anonymous>:16383:28)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js?97065532baea04c9b656:2394:1), <anonymous>:16399:27)
    at Scope.$eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js?97065532baea04c9b656:2394:1), <anonymous>:17682:28)
    at Scope.$digest (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js?97065532baea04c9b656:2394:1), <anonymous>:17495:31) <div ui-grid-menu="" menu-items="menuItems" col="col" class="ng-isolate-scope">
```

But the function is in `ui-grid.core.js`, `ui-grid.core.min.js`, `ui-grid.js` and `ui-grid.min.js`:

```
getSafeText: function (path, lang) {
          var language = lang || service.getCurrentLang(),
            trans = langCache.get(language),
            missing = i18nConstants.MISSING + path,
            getter = $parse(path);

          if (!trans) {
            return missing;
          }

          return getter(trans) || missing;
        },
```

I don't know whats going on with this.
Anyone can help?

Comment: What does your controller definition look like? Maybe the i18nService isn't injected?
(see example in [tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20104%20i18n))

Comment: I've found the problem - I'm already using mu custom `i18nService` which is named same as i18 custom service used inside angular-ui-grid.
Have to rename one of them and problem disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem - I'm already using my own custom i18nService which is named same as i18n custom service used inside angular-ui-grid.

Have to rename one of them and problem disappears.

I, for example, copied whole angular-ui-grid package to local app vendors folder and renamed ui-grid i18nService to something else.

Now it works fine.